# Saving images from dynamic PHP url

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to save a jpg file from a dynamic url, looks like this,

```
http://bks7.books.google.se/books?id=TL3JGsUOArkC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&&source=gbs_api
```

file_get_contents can't get the content correctly, here is my code,

```
<?php
$image_url = "http://bks7.books.google.se/books?id=TL3JGsUOArkC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&&source=gbs_api";
$img =  file_get_contents($image_url);
$folder = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/test.jpg';
file_put_contents($folder, file_get_contents($img));
?>
```

Appreciate any ideas or alternative as "easy" methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you have 2 `file_get_contents` calls. The first call:

```
$img =  file_get_contents($image_url);
```

Returns the response from the request to the URL and stores it in the `$img` variable. The second call:

```
file_put_contents($folder, file_get_contents($img));
```

Doesn't make any sense. Instead, just do this:

```
file_put_contents($folder, $img );
```

Comment: Wow, How stupid of me :) Thank you, I wasted 45 minutes on that.